# How can I create filter for UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to create filter for UnauthorizedAccessException I ddon't know why it is not work in my main filter
at first I try this in my ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute but doesn't worked here

```
private void HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(ExceptionContext context)
{
            var exception = context.Exception as UnauthorizedAccessException;

            var details = new ProblemDetails
            {
                Status = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
                Title = "nauthorized exception",
                Detail = exception.Message
            };

            context.Result = new ObjectResult(details)
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

every other my exceptions work here instead of this

after that I try get that here but not successful again :

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order { get; set; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is HttpResponseException exception)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(exception.Value)
            {
                StatusCode = exception.Status,
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know why only this exception not worked after request send to api :(

Comment: Can you clarify more about the question?

Comment: @FeiHan I want to create authorization filter to throw exception when user not authorized and return custom response to client